# Embed Multiple Word Documents into Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to embed 2 Microsoft Word documents into an Excel worksheet called "Introduction". The first document should be embedded starting at cell A1 and the second one should be embedded starting at cell A62.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
objExcel.Visible = True 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=False
Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("workbook.xlsx")
Set Xlsheet = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Introduction")
Xlsheet.Select
Xlsheet.OLEObjects.Add(FileName:="intro.docx", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
Xlsheet.Range("A62").Select
Xlsheet.OLEObjects.Add(FileName:="methods.docx", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False).Select
objWorkbook1.saveAs "workbook_new.xlsx",51
objWorkbook1.close
objExcel.DisplayAlerts=True
set objExcel=nothing
```

When I run the above code I get an error saying that at line 7 character 32, expected ')'. That would put a ')' after FileName in this line which makes no sense to me.  `Xlsheet.OLEObjects.Add(FileName:="intro.docx", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to `Xlsheet.OLEObjects.Add FileName:="intro.docx", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False`

Comment: Now I'm getting a compilation error, line 7 char 33, expected statement. Code 800A0400

Comment: I finally got it to work doing what you suggested above plus removing the argument names. No idea why it would not work with them. A leading comma was required because `ClassType` is the first argument positionally and `FileType` is the second. `Xlsheet.OLEObjects.Add , "intro.docx", False, False` The same edit was required on line 9.